# How nickel plated copper strip can be welded? What is the optimum thickness of nickel layer?

Tags: metallurgy

I have a trouble with  (resistance) spot welding of nickel plated copper strip to 18650 battery. I tried to weld 0.1mm, 0.2mm and 0.3mm copper strips with 5 micrometers and 10 micrometers nickel plate thickness. Actually i have tried all of the combinations, that is i have tried to weld 0.1mm with 5 microns to 0.3mm with 10 micrometer or 0.2mm with 10 micrometers to 0.1 with 10 micrometers… Additionally, i adjusted power of spot welding machine, i tried with full power and half of the maximum power… Unfortunately all of the trials have failed.
According to you what is the main problem in my case? What is the optimum nickel plate thickness for spot welding application and how it is determined?

Comment: What do you call a failure ? The nickel is unlikely to have much affect.  I found a reference that said the electodes  may need to be cleaned ( smoothed) because copper from the work can transfer to the spot weld tool.